# Splunk equivalent to chained greps for searching within a search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I want to be able to search for patterns in Splunk and then search for another pattern in the search results. I should be able to repeat it for any number of strings.

This is very simple in Linux:

`grep pattern_1 <file name> | grep pattern_2 | grep pattern_3 | grep pattern_4`

How can I do this in Splunk? I would like to make it generic irrespective of the count of sub-searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on [your use case](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/resources/search-processing-language.html), you either do something like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp fieldA=something fieldB=pattern fieldC=*
```

Or you might end up [doing this](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "some literal text"
| rex field=_raw "a pattern of stuff (?<fieldtoextract>regex-goes-here)"
```

Or [possibly this](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp fieldA=*
| stats values(fieldB) by fieldA
| where mvcount(fieldB)>3 AND match(fieldA,"something")
```

Or maybe something else entirely.

If you have sample data, we can help craft some more-specific SPL for you - but there are many *many* ***many*** ways to "search within a search" in Splunk.

Answer (score 0):

The Splunk equivalent to a chain of `grep`s is a chain of searches.  Like with Linux, the command after each pipe processes the results of the command before the pipe.

```
index=<index name> pattern_1 | search pattern_2 | search pattern_3 | search pattern_4
```

But as @warren says, there are many ways to do the same thing in Splunk and your use case may lend itself to a more efficient query.